# Complex number modulus bound

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

If we know that $$\Re\, e^{-z}<1/2$$

Could we know an upper and/or lower bound of $|z|$?

Comment: No for an upper bound, but there is a lower bound of $\ln 2$.

Comment: Can you explain (a little) how to get it? Thanks!!